# data validation for normal classes in python

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

Using `pydantic` I can define a class and out of the box I get data validation for example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):

    age: int
    name: str
```

This raises an error if I pass a value of invalid type to `age`.

Now I am creating a new class, which is not exactly related to api contracts, it's just a "normal" class inside a package with bunch of methods to do something. Now I want to use data validation for that class.

```py
class WhichDoesSomething:

    def __init__(self, some_input: str, some_other_input: int):
        ....
```

I want to have data validation for `some_input` and `some_other_input`. What is the recommended way to go about it. Is it recommended to use `pydantic` or `dataclasses`? Reading on pydantic, it seems like it is designed for enforcing api contracts and design ORM models. And `dataclasses` also seems like something one should use while designing a data model.

Comment: *you have to write the code that does the validation* (or use a library that does that).  Python is a dynamically typed language.

Answer (score 1):

`You can perform the validation in your constructor:

```py
class WhichDoesSomething:

    def __init__(self, some_input: str, some_other_input: int):
        if not isinstance(some_input, str):
            raise TypeError(f"some_input should be of type str, received {type(some_input}")
        if not isinstance(some_other_input, int):
            raise TypeError(f"some_input should be of type int, received {type(some_input}")
```

This will cause a `TypeError` to be raised if the incorrect type is passed to the constructor. If you wish to validate, for example, that a string is fewer than 30 characters long, you can do that too, but it is more correct to throw a `ValueError` when that constraint is violated:

```py
class WhichDoesSomething:

    def __init__(self, some_input: str):
        if len(some_input) > 30:
            raise ValueError(f"some_input should have 30 characters or fewer.")
```

Answer (score 1):

### My Answer

> Now I am creating a new class, which is not exactly related to api contracts, it's just a "normal" class inside a package with bunch of methods to do something. Now I want to use data validation for that class.

If you want to use a normal class and want to use data validation but you don't want to write the validation by yourself, you can use `pydantic.validate_call`.

### My Example

```py
from pprint import pprint

from pydantic import validate_call
from pydantic_core import ValidationError


class WhichDoesSomething:
    def __init__(self, some_input: str, some_other_input: int):
        ...


WhichDoesSomething(1, 'a')  # < no validation


class WhichDoesSomethingValidated:
    @validate_call  # validate with `type annotations`
    def __init__(self, some_input: str, some_other_input: int):
        ...


try:
    WhichDoesSomethingValidated(1, 'a')
except ValidationError as e:
    pprint(e.errors())
    # > [{'input': 1,
    # >   'loc': (0,),
    # >   'msg': 'Input should be a valid string',
    # >   'type': 'string_type',
    # >   'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/string_type'},
    # >  {'input': 'a',
    # >   'loc': (1,),
    # >   'msg': 'Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string as an '
    # >          'integer',
    # >   'type': 'int_parsing',
    # >   'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/int_parsing'}]
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I needed, after looking for hours! :)